# Split nested numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape 28 x 1875. Each element is a 3-element list (only floats). I need to split each of these elements to individual ones, to obtain an array of shape 28x5625(1875*3). I've tried `np.split`, however it only separates each element, but no each sub-element. Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: did you check np.reshape?

Comment: There's ambiguity in your description.  Is the shape (28, 1875, 3) dtype float, or (28, 1875) dtype object?  If object are the elements `list`, or `array`?  If object, why is it that way, instead of being 3d?

Comment: The shape is (28,1875), but each element is a list that comes from a function returning the data that way

Comment: `np.reshape` will probably not work directly but it should if you first convert to list: `np.reshape(arr.tolist(), (*arr.shape[:-1], -1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making a 2d array of lists:

```
In [522]: arr = np.empty(6,object)
In [523]: arr[:] = [list(range(i,i+3)) for i in range(6)]
In [524]: arr = arr.reshape(2,3)
In [525]: arr
Out[525]: 
array([[list([0, 1, 2]), list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3, 4])],
       [list([3, 4, 5]), list([4, 5, 6]), list([5, 6, 7])]], dtype=object)
```

It's easier to fill such an array if it is 1d, which is why I start with (6,) and reshape after.

Paul Panzer's suggestion:

```
In [526]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[526]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4]],

       [[3, 4, 5],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 7]]])
In [527]: _.reshape(2,-1)
Out[527]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]])
```

You can also use `np.stack` (a version of `np.concatenate`) to create a nd array.  It does though, require a 1d object array - hence the `ravel`:

```
In [536]: np.stack(arr.ravel())
Out[536]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

That can be reshaped as needed:

```
In [537]: np.stack(arr.ravel()).reshape(2,-1)
Out[537]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]])
```

In some cases we need to `transpose` axes to get the desired order.